# Increase the maximum length of querystrings in a HttpWebRequest on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, query-string

I'm currently working with an API that receives all the data sent to it via query strings. Some of the query strings I have to send are rather long and the request just dies with an unknown exception, I assume because they exceed the maximum length.

The ideal solution would be to switch to using POST data but as I don't control the API I'd have to wait until the owners of the API can update it.

Is there a way to increase the maximum query string length on Windows Phone to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a solution to this so we're asking the API vendor to switch to POST data.

For reference (as I wasn't able to find this information anywhere) Windows Phone doesn't seem to be able to make requests to URLs over 2078 characters long.